# How to redirect a call to a queue using MS Graph Communications API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to redirect a call to a call queue using the MS Graph Communications API. I'm currently using the C# SDk to communicate with the Graph API.

I know a call queue is just another application created by MS, the id of this application is `11cd3e2e-fccb-42ad-ad00-878b93575e07`. So the following code snipped should make it possible to call this application:

```cs
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var targets = new List<InvitationParticipantInfo>()
{
    new InvitationParticipantInfo
    {
        Identity = new IdentitySet
        {
            Application = new Identity
            {
                DisplayName = "Call Queue",
                Id = "11cd3e2e-fccb-42ad-ad00-878b93575e07"
            }
        }
    }
};

var callbackUri = "https://bot.contoso.com/api/calls/24701998-1a73-4d42-8085-bf46ed0ae039";

await graphClient.Communications.Calls["491f0b00-ffff-4bc9-a43e-b226498ec22a"]
    .Redirect(targets,null,callbackUri)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

However it doesn't allow me to pass the Id of the Call Queue I would like to call. In de MS Graph API the `Identity` class has an extra option `AdditionalData` which has the following prop definition:

```cs
public IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalData { get; set; }
```

My best guess is that we should pass some parameters in here but the official documentation @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-redirect?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp isn't mentioning anything about this possibility.

Does someone know what this parameter could be or, if this isn't the correct way to achieve this goal, how to call the API to transfer to a call queue?

Comment: Can you please share the response from the API.

Comment: I've uploaded it here: http://txt.do/16rkd. I did anonymize the data though. All I do is transfer the call to the application, since I don't know how to transfer it to the Queue. The audio feedback is a busy tone (I guess since the app doesn't reveive the qeueue Id to call)

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT Do you know what the correct syntax is?

Answer (score 0):

Is the "Queue" application something you are hosting yourself?  Or is this a MSFT managed application?  Usually Queues are tenantized instances of a global application, and require an applicationInstance identity to be specified.

Which SDK are you using?  The [Microsoft.Graph.Communications.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Communications.Core) SDK provides extension methods to `IdentitySet` which allow you to get/set different identity types.

```cs
var identitySet = new IdentitySet();

identitySet.SetPhone(new Identity { ... });
var phoneIdentity = identitySet.GetPhone();

identitySet.SetApplicationInstance(new Identity { ... });
var appInstanceIndetity = identitySet.GetApplicationInstance();
```

That being said, bot to bot calls/transfers/invites are not supported in the communications APIs today.  This applies to application instances as well.

Regards,
Kamil

Comment: Hi, The Queue Application is the MSFT managed application. I'm indeed using the MS Graph Code SDK. And I also tried to transfer the call to an Application instance and as you confirm this does not work.

However from the teams admin panel you can transfer a call from an Auto Attendant to a Call Queue, so it's technicly possible to transfer from one application to another (since both are an application).

When will this be available via the API?

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this method :

```
    private async Task RedirectAsync(string callId)
    {
        try
        {
            var targets = new List<InvitationParticipantInfo>()
        {
            new InvitationParticipantInfo
            {
                Identity = new IdentitySet
                {

                }
            }
        };
            targets[0].Identity.SetApplicationInstance(new Identity { Id = "GuidApplicationInstanceOfCallQueue", ODataType = "microsoft.graph.identity" });              
            var callbackUri = "https://fakefake.ngrok.io/callback";
            await graphServiceClient.Communications.Calls[callId]
                .Redirect(targets, null, callbackUri)
                .Request()
                .PostAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
    }
```